# Carry observations forward n rows by group

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo

I have data like this, which is grouped by 'orgid':

```
orgid date    type counter
12345 1-1-17  sale  3
12345 1-2-17  NA   NA
12345 1-3-17  NA   NA
78945 1-1-17  NA   NA
78945 1-2-17  free 2
78945 1-3-17  NA   NA
```

For each 'orgid', I would like to "drag down" the 'type' N-1 rows, where N is defined by the 'counter' column. The result should look like below:

```
orgid date    type counter
12345 1-1-17  sale   3
12345 1-2-17  sale   NA
12345 1-3-17  sale   NA
78945 1-1-17  NA     NA
78945 1-2-17  free   2
78945 1-3-17  free   NA
```

I believe I can use `na.locf` in the `zoo` package, but I have not been able to crack the code. Any ideas?

Comment: Your carry-forward seems oblivious of `orgid`, should it be grouped there as well? Or are `orgid` and `date` irrelevant to this question?

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for replying. The dates go for 2 full years in the full data and there are a multitude of orgids, each with various "types" (we could call them events). I believe this can be pulled off while ignoring orgid & date but wanted to include the full data for context.

Comment: @Jason in this specific example you posted, if the first `counter` value was 4 would you like your 4th row to have type = sale, or not?

Comment: @AntoniosK The 4 refers to 4 total days, so we need to fill 3 more rows down, to the 4th row (if that makes sense).

Comment: Yes, just wanted to make sure it doesn't matter that you have a different `orgid` in your 4th row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I don't think you can use `zoo::na.locf` for this, I don't think it honors a limiting factor.</strike> (Thanks to Henrik for setting me straight!)

Two solutions, and I'm confident a `data.table` guru can add a relevant third:

### Base R

```
do.call("rbind.data.frame",
        lapply(split(dat, cumsum(!is.na(dat$type))),
               function(d) within(d, type[seq_len(min(nrow(d), counter[1]))] <- type[1])
               ))
```

### `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(!is.na(type))) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(type = if_else(row_number() <= counter[1], type[1], type)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp)
```

### Data

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
orgid date    type counter
12345 1-1-17  sale  3
12345 1-2-17  NA   NA
12345 1-3-17  NA   NA
78945 1-1-17  NA   NA
78945 1-2-17  free 2
78945 1-3-17  NA   NA')
```

Comment: this is so close! It comes up one row short, so I think I needed N rows rather than N-1. But I can change the definition of the counter to accomplish that. Would you mind explaining what the second mutate does?

Comment: Because `mutate` operates on a whole column at once, I need to assign something to every row within the specific group (`grp`). In this case, I am "confident" that the first `counter` is the number of rows to be modified, and `dplyr::row_number()` identifies the row number within the grouping, always starting at 1, so this effectively does `if_else(1:4 <= 3, firstvalue, whatwastherebefore)`, so all after 3 (in the first group) remain unchanged (`NA`). I don't know what you mean by "comes up own row short", my output is identical to your expected output ...